# C++ compiles with clang from command line, but not using CMake

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, cmake, clang

I am trying to compile a simple test project to make sure all my tools, such as CMake, Boost, Clang are working.

The source code I am trying to compile is LibLinkTest.cpp:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string str{"test passed"};
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    boost::filesystem::path p{argv[1]};

    try {
        std::cout << p.string() << std::endl;
        if (exists(p)) {
            if (is_regular_file(p)) {
                std::ifstream file{p.c_str()};
                std::string line;
                if (file.good() && file.is_open()) {
                    while (file >> line) {
                        std::cout << line << std::endl;
                    }
                }
                file.close();
          } else if (is_directory(p)) {
              std::cout << p.string() << " is a directory " << std::endl;                                                 // path stream inserter
          } else
              std::cout << p.string() << " exists, but is neither a regular file nor a directory" << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << p.string() << " does not exist" << std::endl;
        }
      }
    catch (const filesystem_error& ex) {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Running:

```
c++ -std=c++11 -I /usr/boost_1_54_0/boost/ LibLinkTest.cpp -o LibTest -L /usr/boost_1_54_0/lib/ -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system
```

compiles it just fine and the code runs (with a seg fault, but I'll address that separately).

However, I want to use CMake with my other projects. Trying to compile LibLinkTest.cpp with the following CMakeLists.txt causes linking errors.

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED (VERSION 2.6)

PROJECT(BoostTest CXX)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++")

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.54.0 COMPONENTS filesystem system REQUIRED)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( 
    ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}
    /usr/include/
    /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/
)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(
    LibTest 
    LibLinkTest.cpp
)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(LibTest boost_filesystem boost_system)
```

The output from running `cmake ../` is:

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 5.0.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   system
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

And finally running `make` gives the error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target LibTest
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/LibTest.dir/LibLinkTest.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable LibTest
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::string::c_str() const", referenced from:
      boost::system::system_error::what() const in LibLinkTest.cpp.o
      boost::filesystem::path::c_str() const in LibLinkTest.cpp.o
  "std::string::empty() const", referenced from:
      boost::system::system_error::what() const in LibLinkTest.cpp.o
  "std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::good() const", referenced from:
      _main in LibLinkTest.cpp.o
```

It seems like a setting in CMake is not correct, perhaps something that points to the std c++ lib. Does anyone know how I can configure CMake correctly?

Comment: `cmake -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON` and then find out what the command line is.

Comment: Also, are you using cmake-gui to configure the proejct?

Comment: No, not been using the gui. I have solved the problem now, see answer below. It seems I have a simple typo in one of the CXX flags.

Comment: The gui or `cmake -i` can be very helpful figuring those kinds of hassles out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this by changing the line:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++")
```

to

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++")
```

It seems like I had just made a typo in the CMakeLists.txt.

On a side note, does anyone know why I need to set this flag? Is it a C++11 thing? It also seems to have solved my issues with the seg fault that I was getting when compiling from the command line.

Comment: guessing: libc++ is the gnu library, libstdc++ is the clang version?

Comment: Your boost version is compiled with libstdc++ library and can't be 'just linked' to libc++ one.

Comment: And that's why you should always compile Boost yourself :D

Comment: Interestingly I did compile boost myself from source. Does this mean that I compiled boost with different settings to what CMake was using? I am on OS X 10.9 and installed XCode command line tools to get a C++ compiler, but it seems I have clang++ and g++ installed, with /usr/bin/c++ symlinking to clang++.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the line

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(LibTest boost_filesystem boost_system)
```

to

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(LibTest ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

The `FIND_PACKAGE` command sets the `Boost_LIBRARIES` variable to what you need to link with.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I don't think this was causing the problem. See my answer below for what I have just found to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you see these two lines from the output

```
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
```

It tells you that it might not be clang that is used to compile the source. To see if it is, to e.g.

```
$ c++ --version
```

to see what compiler it actually is. If it doesn't say clearly you may want to do e.g.

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/c++
```

and if it's a symbolic link then check the link (and so on). On my system (Ubuntu 13.10) the file `/usr/bin/c++` is a symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/c++` which is a symbolic link to `/usr/bin/g++`, meaning that on my system the command `c++` is actually the GCC C++ compiler.

To make sure you use clang, then redo the `cmake` command (from a clean folder, that you haven't run `cmake` in before) with the environment variable `CXX` set to `clang++`, like

```
$ CXX=clang++ cmake path/to/folder/with/CMakeLists.txt
```

---

Pro-tip: Make a separate folder for building, and run `cmake` from it. Then you can easily clean it up by just removing it if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. /usr/bin/c++ symlinks to /usr/bin/clang++ on my system. In my command line compiling tests, I ran it using both c++ and clang++ and both worked. I am already using a /build/ directory for the CMake generating to make things easier, but thanks for the tip